# Kill a thread locked with dispatch_sync

Tags: ios, pthreads, grand-central-dispatch

Is it possible to kill a thread that is locked due to a dispatch_sync? Here is the code:

```
dispatch_sync(q_, ^{
  ...
});
```

Here is the stack trace when it is locked:

```
#0  0x00007fff8d69951a in semaphore_wait_trap ()
#1  0x00007fff9aad7c5b in _os_semaphore_wait ()
#2  0x0000000100aec692 in _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow ()
```

I tried using `pthread_kill` but the thread does not terminate.

Answer (score 2):

If you look through all the POSIX information, it is possible.

In reality, forget it. You'll never make it work. If you have a deadlock in your code, the only way to get rid of the deadlock is to fix your code.

BTW, a deadlock on an iOS device is much much worse than a crash. When an app crashes, many users don't even take any notice, they just start it again. When an app deadlocks, the user needs to use a much more complicated process to kill the app manually.

As a rule, I'd avoid `dispatch_sync` as much as possible.

Comment: This is good advice, but deserves some more explanation. Forcibly killing a thread is a bad idea because any resources allocated by any code run on that thread will be leaked. You have no way of knowing at runtime if an arbitrary thread is deadlocked or just busy. If you have enough information to know it's deadlocked, then logically you have enough information to prevent the deadlock, which you should. Lastly, `dispatch_sync` has *some* valid uses, but it shouldn't be used as an adapter for making asynchronous code synchronous, or for interlocking threads (which is how I often see it used.)

Comment: I am not saying that killing the thread is the good solution, I am just trying to kill it to experiment something. Until now, I did not find a way to kill it in order to release the deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

[`pthread_kill()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_kill.html) does not "kill" a thread in terms of ending it, it just sends it a signal.

The function of choice to (try to) end a thread is [`pthread_cancel()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cancel.html).

Cancellation however only happpens when the code execution "passes" a cancellation point. The latter are well defined. [See here for a list.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_09_05_02)